# Is it possible to install Opposing Fronts via Steam?

Tags: steam, company-of-heroes

I have Company of Heroes as a retail copy. I was wondering if it is possible for me to make this a Steam copy somehow? I was thinking if I buy the addon pack, Opposing Fronts, I might be able to do that. Does anyone know if this is possible? [Some Steam forum users](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2099170) suggest that it may not work. Although I am sceptical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to convert a retail copy of company of heroes to a steam copy. Steam has a list of the games where this is possible, this is mostly valve games.

I had this question myself a year back or so, and I ended up purchasing all the games once again on steam.